# How can assure users enter correct coordinate values?

Tags: java

So I have a composition program that has a `Point` Class and inside that a `Line`class which uses the Point class `isValid` method, to make sure a user enters correct values before continuing.

Basically when they enter the values in the `enterLine()` in my main class, they should have to keep entering until it satisfies the rules of `isValid()` in Point, and `validateLine()` in Line.

```
// This method is in the Point class and will be used by validateLine()
public static boolean isValid(int x, int y) 
{
  Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
  int maxHeight = screenSize.height; 
  int maxWidth = screenSize.width;

  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > maxWidth || y > maxHeight)
  {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```
 // This method is in the Line class, uses isValid() from Point Class
public static boolean validateLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int width)
{
    if (Point.isValid(x1, y1) && Point.isValid(x2, y2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
// This method is in main, it prompts user to enter two valid Points.
public static Line enterLine(int line, Scanner kb)
{
  System.out.println("Please enter two x's and y's values, a width, and color");
  int x1 = kb.nextInt();
  int x2 = kb.nextInt();
  int y1 = kb.nextInt();
  int y2 = kb.nextInt();
  int newWidth = kb.nextInt();
  String color = kb.next();


  return new Line(x1, x2, y1, y2, color, newWidth);

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking how to repeatedly prompt the user for `x` and `y` values, if it is not valid, then you would use a `do while` or `while` loop.

You would do something similar to:

```
public static Line enterLine(int line, Scanner kb) {
  do {
        System.out.println("Please enter two x's and y's values, a width, and color");
        int x1 = kb.nextInt();
        int x2 = kb.nextInt();
        int y1 = kb.nextInt();
        int y2 = kb.nextInt();
        int newWidth = kb.nextInt();
        String color = kb.next();
 } while(!validateLine(x1, y1,  x2,  y2,  newWidth));

  return new Line(x1, x2, y1, y2, color, newWidth);

}
```

Comment: Ah, ok. But because the `validateLine`' s parameters are not found by this method how could i fix that ? Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, make sure that the method `isValid` and `validateLine` is in the same class. Then, if you are calling these methods from another class, then you would create a new instance of a class, then call these methods. For example, `ClassName newClass = new ClassName();` Where `ClassName` is the name of the class containing the methods `isValid` and `validateLine`. Then, you would call `newClass.validateLine()`

Comment: The program is a composition meaning there is an outer class `Point` with a inner class `Line`. `Line` has the `validateLine()` and `Point` the `isValid` as required by my assignment. I also did create an instance class for the `Line` as in `Line  line1 = new Line();` now should I add `line1` as a parameter to the current method `enterLine()` and then do the `line1.validateLine()` ?

Comment: I would recommend you research how to do this, then.

Comment: As this is an assignment, I cannot help you further. There are strict rules here regarding help with assignment's or homework.